# Typo3 8.7 export plugin content as RSS feed

Tags: rss, typo3-extensions

I want to export the contents of my extension's plugin to RSS. I have followed a number of tutorials online but none of them are working.

In my Plugin's setup-ts I have added the following (newsevents is my extension, nepi5 is the plugin within that extension)

```
 pageNewsRSS = PAGE
 pageNewsRSS{
     typeNum = 9818
     10 < tt_content.list.20.newsevents_nepi5
     config{
         disableAllHeaderCode = 1
         additionalHeaders = Content-Type:application/rss+xml;charset=utf-8
         metaCharset = utf-8
         xhtml_cleaning = 0
         admPanel = 0
         debug = 0
         no_cache = 1
         disablePrefixComment = 1
     }
 }
```

In my template file I have the following:

```
    <rss version="2.0">
        <channel>
            <title>Title</title>
            <link>https://www.URLLINK.com</link>
            <description>Description</description>
            <f:for each="{articles}" as="article" iteration="iterator">         
                <item>
                    <title{article.titel}</title>
                    <description>{article.content}</description>
                </item>   
            </f:for>
        </channel>      
    </rss>
```

...when I view the page using typeNum 9818 (&type=9818), the correct action for my plugin runs, the correct data is passed through to the template, but the page is still written with HTML elements with a head tag, a body tag and within the body tag.
I'm obviously missing something major regarding templating. Any help appreciated.
I'm using a plugin in my extension because I use a Flexform to choose which items from a list I want to show.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problems result from skipping a proper page templating and trying to generate the whole page in the plugin.

I would try to build a fluid page template which includes the output of the plugin. and the plugin just renders the inner loop.